# Clear email reminders from all Google calendar entries?

Tags: google-calendar

How can I remove all notifications from all events in a given Google Calendar?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you talking about the email reminders that you get from a calendar event? Just delete the email messages. They have a pretty generic format so if your email client has decent search capability they'll be easy to find. If that's not what you're asking about, please clarify.

Comment: I don't want to remove emails. I want to remove reminders. That is, I want to alter all events in a given Google Calendar such that none of them will ever again send me a reminder (be it email, popup, etc). I want to do this without interacting without any single given event in the calendar. I want to do it en masse within the scope of a specified Google Calendar. How can I remove all reminders from all events in a given Google Calendar?

Comment: leave a bad review on google store (I don't think google care of feedbacks)

Answer (score 5):

Follow these instructions to remove all reminders from all events: [Disable notifications for all events on a calendar.](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37170)

***Edit:*** The following part from that page may be helpful:

To turn off all notifications for Google Calendar, you can change your default settings for your calendar. Since notifications sync between your mobile device and your computer, you can change your settings from either the app or a computer.

*Mobile directions*

- Open the Google Calendar app .
- Go to the main menu in the top left .
- Choose Settings at the bottom.
- Choose one of your calendars, like Events.
- Touch a notification and choose No notification. Repeat for each notification.
- If you have multiple accounts or calendars, repeat these steps for each calendar.

*Computer directions*

- Open Google Calendar.
- Click the settings gear in the top right .
- Select Settings.
- Click the Calendars tab at the top.
- Click Edit notifications next to your calendar's name.
- Click remove next to each notification.
- If you have multiple calendars, repeat these steps for each calendar.

Comment: This is very helpful.  This only clears notifications from events whose notifications I have not manually managed in the past?  Is that right?  That is to say -- if I've gone to an event in the past and manually added a reminder, this will *not* clear *that* reminder?  Is that right?

Comment: @lance: I can't answer this because personally I don't use Google Calendars. I can only suggest you try it.

Comment: I suspect that's the case... I removed the default reminders for a calendar, but this doesn't remove the custom reminders in each task...

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

I have found that bulk editing event specific notifications in Google Calendar is not possible, as of now at least.

The only way to remove event specific notifications, is to follow the procedure named "Change event notifications" at the [Google Calendar help page](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?hl=en&visit_id=636868857355298635-3845459626&rd=1#) for each of them.

Answer (score -2):

Just select the reminder, tap the right top corner, select delete, choose this and all following reminders
This is for mobile calender app(Android) updated version

Comment: As this is Web Apps, we generally expect solutions to be for the web application. Solutions that rely on a smartphone app aren't helpful here.